# Increasing size on /home/user

Tags: disk

I have a problem. While installing Ubuntu I accidently give my /home/ayoub 8 GB and all 50Gb is on /home. how can I increase the size of /home/ayoub if it's possible

```
sudo parted -l
```

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB   472MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      473MB   578MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      578MB   595MB   16,8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      595MB   891GB   891GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      891GB   912GB   20,8GB  ext4
 6      912GB   916GB   4000MB  linux-swap(v1)
 7      916GB   1000GB  84,3GB  ext4


Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SNAT1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16,8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   128GB  127GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      128GB   128GB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

```
df -h
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  2,1M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        19G   17G  1,2G  94% /
tmpfs           3,9G   28M  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop4      1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop19     152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36
/dev/loop7      194M  194M     0 100% /snap/mailspring/346
/dev/loop9       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop10     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop14     2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop13      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/258
/dev/loop12     1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop15     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop17     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop18     4,2M  4,2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop20     4,2M  4,2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop22     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
/dev/loop24      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop27      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop28     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
/dev/loop29      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop2      195M  195M     0 100% /snap/mailspring/326
/dev/loop8      152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40
/dev/loop3      174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/34
/dev/loop26      36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop1       75M   75M     0 100% /snap/sqlitebrowser-casept/2
/dev/loop6      181M  181M     0 100% /snap/spotify/35
/dev/loop23      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/254
/dev/loop30     194M  194M     0 100% /snap/mailspring/338
/dev/loop25      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop16     144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop21     175M  175M     0 100% /snap/spotify/32
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/sda7        77G  6,8G   67G  10% /home
/dev/sda2        96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           785M   16K  785M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           785M   32K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `sudo parted -l` and `df -h`

Comment: thank you. you can see the results from the images

Comment: I don't see that you have a separate partition for `/home/ayoub`. There is 77G on `/home` and 19G on `/`. Most of the space is on your ntfs "Basic data partition".

Comment: There is no separate partition for `/home/ayoub`, so the data in this folder can eat up the whole of the `/home` partition, which is 77G, as @pLumo states.

Comment: the system tells me that there is not enough storage. The last time I checked I think there is like 8GB for my user

Comment: The screenshots show only a `/home`, not any other configuration (somehow expected). And please avoid posting screenshots. Copy that results then paste it here (click {} and paste inside).

Comment: This is probably due to low space on `/`, not `/home`. 19G is not a lot. Start Ubuntu from a Live USB disk, run gparted and shrink the "Basic data partition" (`/dev/sda6`) for 10G or so, and give the then free space to `/` (`/dev/sda7`).

Comment: is it possible to extend / size ?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions